# Super User Question of the Week #31

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 31 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 2):

In a busy week of Windows 8 news, and the developer preview a fair few Windows 8 questions showed, having myself installed it I took the opportunity to stay on top of a few.

This one in particular caught my eye as a strange question to be asking in the Windows world, where closing an app hasn't really changed in almost 2 decades. I quickly uploaded the first picture I found showing a keyboard windows key.

> [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-metro-app)

Comment: Are we really able to write an entire post on this though?

Comment: @Simon there's already [discussion underway of a general Windows 8 post](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OZuEU4PmsL2kZ7y2GnFZQTMYVkmk8gJRV7l51knBvoQ/edit?hl=en_US). Also, remember that QotW does not have to be super in-depth, it can just report on what the post was very briefly.

Comment: @nhinkle oh okay, didn't see that

Comment: I like this one.  I anticipate a **flood** of questions on "How do I close this app??"  The Palm Treo phones had a similar standby-type memory manager and I remember people asking "How do I close it?"  An interesting blog post should be about the suspend process feature.